# Installing Oracle 10g on Panasas PAS12 (NAS)

Tags: nfs, oracle10g

We are using Panasas PAS12 (running in pNFS protocol) internally in our team, and are currently thinking of migrating our Oracle 10g in it.

We have two sides among ourselves. On one hand, Oracle 10g should be installed in SAN and block-level filesystem so it can manages its own cache and file I/O. This will result in better I/O performance and less expensive (we need just a bunch of disks). On the other hand, PAS offers high performance I/O, high availability, management console and other good stuff.

So I would like to hear from you whether it is a smart decision to install Oracle 10g on Panasas (or any NAS system)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First questions is: Has Oracle certified Pansas and will support your installation if you use it? Oracle 11g and up has got an internal NFS client but does not support pNFS yet so half the benefit in that goes away.

I've seen many VLDB deployments on NFS, mostly Netapp, with no problems with reliability or performance (when planned properly).
I run several mid-size databases on Netapp NFS, both physical and some virtualized, with no problems either.

The "safe bet" would be to use Oracle ASM with normal block storage.